# Drupal hook_search function location

Tags: search, drupal, function, hook

I can't for the life of me figure out where the hook_search function in drupal is located. Is it something I need to add to a file to access?

Answer (score 3):

Hook functions don't exist by name -- they indicate a naming convention that can be followed to respond to that particular "hook"...

An example would be the [node_search()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_search) function. When the search module calls module_invoke_all('search'), all functions named *foo*_search(), where *foo* is the name of an enabled module, will be called. The details of the search hook in particular are found on [api.drupal.org](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_search/6).

Answer (score 1):

```
function hook_search($op = 'search', $keys = null) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'name':
      return t('content');
    case 'reset':
      variable_del('node_cron_last');
      return;
    case 'search':
      $find = do_search($keys, 'node', 'INNER JOIN {node} n ON n.nid = i.sid '. node_access_join_sql() .' INNER JOIN {users} u ON n.uid = u.uid', 'n.status = 1 AND '. node_access_where_sql());
      $results = array();
      foreach ($find as $item) {
        $node = node_load(array('nid' => $item));
        $extra = node_invoke_nodeapi($node, 'search result');
        $results[] = array('link' => url('node/'. $item),
                           'type' => node_invoke($node, 'node_name'),
                           'title' => $node->title,
                           'user' => theme('username', $node),
                           'date' => $node->changed,
                           'extra' => $extra,
                           'snippet' => search_excerpt($keys, check_output($node->body, $node->format)));
      }
      return $results;
  }
}
```